# SQL - Select inside Select

Tags: sql

My skills with SQL are simple, so i'm not sure how to do this.. Here it goes.

Lets consider this.

```
Table A
ID              Name              LastNameID
1               Jonh              23
2               Helen             19

Table B
ID              LastName
23              Bauer
19              Summers
```

.

```
SELECT ID Name LastNameID FROM TableA
```

How can i add another Select inside that one that will return the LastName from Table B based on the LastNameID in Table A.

In this case i usually use a simple function with the Programming language that i use to do that for each returned Row.

But i think its time to do that with SQL alone.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to join the tables using the LastNameId field:

```
SELECT TableA.[Name] AS FirstName, TableB.LastName
FROM TableA 
  INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.LastNameId = TableB.LastNameId
```

Comment: I'm trying your answers... But now i gotta apply them to do those relations between 4 tables.. It might take a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "how to do it with a select inside select". Usually, such queries are written in the form of joins, not as sub-selects. Doing joins is better than doing sub-selects for small number of tables.

The query for your application would be

```
SELECT firstNames.Name, lastNames.LastName FROM TableA firstNames, TableB lastNames
WHERE firstNames.LastNameId = lastNames.LastNameId;
```

This is the same as writing the query in an explicit join form as shown by Chris in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It might do it

Comment: A well written database engine will usually plan the queries the same way. But using joins is more idiomatic.

Comment: jrharshath could you explain how your code worsk? So that i can apply it in big scale in my application. Would this work on Sql Server CE?

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here, but if you actually have the first name in one table and last name in another table linked by an ID - I think it is time to review the basics.  Start with looking at the Northwind database andmthen some of the database starter kits [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-samples-starter-kits.aspx)

Comment: I used First and Last Name as the more simple possible.. It was just something it came to my head. I would never do that of course. But the solution would be very good to other situations.